# Use d3 to generate markup but not manipulate the DOM?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Given the following code, I can append an svg circle to a body tag.

```
d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 30)
    .attr("cy", 30)
    .attr("r", 20);
```

But say I want to use d3 to just generate the markup:

```
<svg><circle cx="30" cy="30" r="20"/></svg>
```

and assign it to a javascript variable to eventually be rendered on the page. In this case I don't want d3 to directly manipulate the DOM, but I want to use its magic to generate my markup.

How do I go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a lightweight [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) to create an in-memory tree which is not part of the actual DOM tree. Because the `DocumentFragment` interface inherits from the `Node` interface you could easily wrap it in a D3 selection and do your normal D3 operations starting from the new *virtual* root. When finished the desired source string can be obtained from the `outerHTML` property of the root node, i.e. your appended `<svg>`.

```js
// Create a document fragment in memory and wrap a D3 selection around it.
var doc = d3.select(document.createDocumentFragment());

// Do your normal D3 stuff.
var svg = doc.append("svg")
svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 30)
  .attr("cy", 30)
  .attr("r", 20);

// 1. Obtain your source string from the outerHTML property.
var svgString = svg.node().outerHTML;
console.dir(svgString);

// 2. You can run a normal selection on the root
// This variant does not even require keeping a
// reference to the appended elements.
svgString = doc.select("svg").node().outerHTML;
console.dir(svgString);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

**Note:** As I just realized, there is one drawback, though, since IE still does not support `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` properties for SVG content. Therefore, this approach is no viable solution if you need to support IE.